# How to create excel forumlae using column headers?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formulae which is:

```
="do.something("&BA2&",'"&LEFT(BI2,FIND("_",BI2)-1)&",something) as "&BA2&","
```

But rather than specifying the columns, how can I create this using the data that exists in the first cell in each column, i.e. the column headers.

So effectively, I would want something like:

```
="do.something("@[Data_Header_1]2",'"&LEFT(@[Data_Header_2]2,FIND("_",@[Data_Header_2]2)-1)&",something) as "@[Data_Header_1]2","
```

But obviously this is invalid.

My data is likely to move around, hence why I would like to reference it using column headers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your column headings are in row 1, use Match to find the column:

```
column_number1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Data_Header_1", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1"), 0)
column_number2 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Data_Header_2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1"), 0)
```

To refer to the column, just use `Columns`, e.g.

```
Columns(column_number1).Select
```

Or - depending on what you're using it for:

```
Columns(column_number2).Address
```

Answer (score 0):

Just point directly to the cell. So if the table starts in A1 and you want the first header, refer to it as `A$1`.

The `$` is for fixing the row, so you're still referring to the first row even if you drag down the formula

Comment: The problem is, I might not be interested in the data from A1, I could have say 100 columns of data and I might be interested only in C1 and BC1. The columns may also move in the future, which is why I would like to point to this data using column headers

Comment: "Column headers" would be in row 1, presumably. Therefore they could be in A$1 or C$1 or BC$1 - note the $ sign before the 1 which ensures that it is always the first row which is referred to. Notice no $ sign before A or B or BC. Therefore, if you write `=A$1` anywhere in column A and copy it to the right, the reference will change to point to the column header in its respective column.